# ImportError: No module named lsb_release

Tags: 12.04, python, lsb-release

When I run `lsb_release -a` , it shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 26, in <module>
import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named lsb_release
```

I have change default python version Python2.7 to python2.6. Ubuntu 12.04

how to solve this problem?

Comment: And how did you make that change?

Comment: goto this link http://web.mit.edu/6.00/www/handouts/pybuntu.html      here is steps how to change default python version . i am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Please add what you did to the question.

Comment: Possibly you run into [this (pretty old) bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/543514).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 has the `lsb_release.py` file installed for Python 2.7 as well and `lsb_release` seems to work under python2.7 as well. You can try this by doing:

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/lsb_release
```

If that works, make a backup of the file `/usr/bin/lsb_release` and change the first line to read:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
```

(you can experiment with the `-Es` options, I would leave them out intially).

Once you can run `apt-get` again, reinstall python3 and it dependencies. You can determine the direct dependencies by using `apt-cache depends python3` and use `apt-rdepends` or `reverse-depends` (both have to be installed) to get dependencies recursively.

**Note** - Find Original [Answer by Anthon on unix.stckexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174933/apt-broken-after-upgrading-python-on-14-04-no-module-named-lsb-release)

Comment: i need same solution for python2.6 i am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This difference occurs between python 3.5 and python 3.6. You can confirm that by doing just `python3.5 -c 'import lsb_release'` and similar for python3.6